# jqGrid inline search cutting off search textboxes

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that has inline search at the top. Locally, it looks beautiful in both Chrome and IE11. However, when I move it to my QA environment, it looks awful in IE, and fine in Chrome. I've fixed most of it, but I can't fix how the search input boxes are displaying. They are centered and cut off.

[image]

Here is my code for the jqGrid:

```
jQuery("#childGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'ServiceDelivery.aspx/GetChildSearchResults',
    mtype: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Case ID', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'DOB', 'City', 'State', 'Svc No Cost'],
    colModel: [
               { name: 'CaseID', index: 'CaseID', key: true, search: true, hidden: false, width: 75, align: "left", editable: false, sorttype: 'integer', searchoption: { sopt: ['eq'] } },
               { name: 'ChildLastName', index: 'ChildLastName', key: true, search: true, hidden: false, width: 120, align: "left", editable: false, sorttype: 'string', searchoption: { sopt: ['cn'] } },
               { name: 'ChildFirstName', index: 'ChildFirstName', key: true, search: true, hidden: false, width: 120, align: "left", sorttype: 'string', searchoption: { sopt: ['cn'] }, editable: false },
               { name: 'DateOfBirth', index: 'DateOfBirth', key: true, search: true, hidden: false, width: 75, align: "left", editable: false, sorttype: 'date', searchoption: { sopt: ['cn'] }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'n/j/Y' }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] } },
               { name: 'ResidesTown', index: 'ResidesTown', key: true, search: true, hidden: false, width: 120, align: "left", editable: false, sorttype: 'string', searchoption: { sopt: ['cn'] }, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'ResidesState', index: 'ResidesState', key: true, search: true, hidden: false, width: 50, align: "left", editable: false, sorttype: 'string', searchoption: { sopt: ['cn'] }, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'IsServicesAtNoCost', index: 'IsServicesAtNoCost', key: true, search: true, hidden: false, width: 80, align: "left", editable: false, sorttype: 'boolean', searchoption: {sopt: ['cn'] } }

    ],
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {

        if (postData.searchField == null) {
            postData.searchField = "";
            postData._search = false;
            postData.searchOper = "";
            postData.searchString = "";
            postData.fein = $$('hidFEIN').val();
            postData.spop = $$('hidSPOP').val();
        }
        return JSON.stringify(postData);

    },
    jsonReader: {
        id: "CaseID",

        root: function (obj) { 
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.rows;
        },
        page: function (obj) {
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.page;

        }, total: function (obj) {
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.total;
        }, records: function (obj) {
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.rows.length;
        }, repeatitems: false

    },
    loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {

    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {

    },
    loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
        alert("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    },
    pager: jQuery('#childPager'),
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [50, 100, 150, 200],
    sortname: '',
    sortorder: "",
    modal: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    loadonce: true, //false,
    width: 690,
    height: 200,
    editurl: '',
    grouping: false,
    footerrow: false,
    hoverrows: false,
    grouping: false,
    footerrow: false,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    caption: "<h2>Child Search</h2>",
    sortname: '',
    sortorder: "asc",
    onSelectRow: function () {
        getSelectedRowData('childSearch'); return false;
    }
}).navGrid("#childPager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true, view: false })
$('#childGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: true, enableClear: true});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've added:

```
cmTemplate: {searchoptions: {attr: {style: "text-align:left; width:120px"}}},
```

which has fixed the problem. I'm not 100% sure why, but it did.

Comment: I think you have some external css which causes the problem. The clear test of this is to use only and only jqgrid setup with css  and js files to see if the problem exists.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am thinking as well. The cmTemplate has overwritten what I believe is a .td css in an external file.